# VSCode - Autocomplete/Suggest user-typed CSS class names?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vue-component

Does anyone know if there is a way to have VSCode autocomplete/suggest CSS class names that the user has typed in the document?

I usually work with **Vue** files and after I type a new CSS class name in the Template (HTML) section, I go to the Style section and I want to write css for that class. But I always write the class name character by character, not to mention most of the time I forget about the HTML structure and my own naming convention so I have to scroll all the way back up, see how I named things and go back to CSS and rewrite those names.

I already have these extensions enabled:

- [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://github.com/Zignd/HTML-CSS-Class-Completion)
- [HTML CSS Support](https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css)
- [Vetur](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur)

Is there a VSCode setting or extension that provides such feature?

Answer (score 1):

*IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML* should work. Are you sure it's enabled and no settings are overwriting/blocking it?
Alternative could be [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion)

Comment: IntelliSense work as intended but it doesn't do what I described. The alternative extension you posted also doesn't work in .Vue files. I think it's only for HTML/PHP files

Comment: In their [example](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion) IntelliSense does autocomplete CSS classes.

Comment: Yes it does, and it does for me too. But it works with CSS classes that are installed through npm and other means. It doesn't scan or know about user-written class names.

Comment: This one should work: [I will work](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css).

Comment: I tried that one before (mentioned it in the post ) It doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work. Nothing seems to work actually. VSCode has a big problem with CSS. If I `import styles from '../styles/Layout.module.css';` it must provide a list of classes from the module when I type `styles.`. But it doesn't.